# How to create single Video from different types of HDR Images (*.exr , *.hdr ) formats in single folder using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, sh

I want to create a single video file using the different formats of Images (`*.exr`, `*.hdr`, `*.png`, ...) from the input folder with different image names.

```sh
ffmpeg -framerate 24 \
       -i Folder/input1.exr \
       -i Folder/input2.exr \
       -i Folder/input000001.hdr \
       -i Folder/input000002.hdr \
       -i Folder/input%06d.hdr \
       -i Folder/input%06d.png \  # more inputs here ...
       -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 13 -pix_fmt yuv444p10le \
       Output_exr_264.mp4
```

I tried this sample command but I got various errors like:

> input%06d.hdr: No such file or directory

or the video not getting the play it shows the duration is `0`.
Does anyone have an idea about this query?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a couple of input filenames that you thought `input%06.hdr`, etc. would match? And also clarify whether those filenames contain spaces, line breaks, etc.

Comment: @ oguz ismail File name may contain the Space but not other like line breaks, etc..

Comment: `input%06d.hdr` is expecting a numerical sequence: `input000001.hdr`, `input000002.hdr`, `input000003.hdr`, etc. Check that they are named properly for the sequence to match and that there are no breaks in the sequence.